# In Unity how can i create number of Spheres Game Objects with random number of Heights and objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i want is to make a script that will create on a Terrain random number of gameObjects in this case Spheres and that it each one will have random Height.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Random_Objects : MonoBehaviour {

    public int Random_Object_Min = 1, Random_Object_Max = 51;
    public int Random_Height_Min = 5, Random_Height_Max = 100;
    [HideInInspector] private int[] Objects_Number;
    [HideInInspector] private int[] Random_Heights;
    [HideInInspector] private int Area_Size_To_Build = 0;
    [HideInInspector] private Vector3 terrainSize;
    [HideInInspector] private GameObject s;
    [HideInInspector] private ArrayList myNodes;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        Objects_Number = new int[Random.Range (Random_Objects_Min,Random_Objects_Max)];
        Random_Heights = new int[Random.Range(Random_Height_Min, Random_Height_Max)];

        myNodes = new ArrayList ();
        for (int i = 0; i < Objects_Number.Length; i++) 
        {
            s = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            s.transform.position = new Vector3 ((Random.value*461)+10, (Random.value*300)+10, 0F);
            //s.transform.localScale += new Vector3(

            myNodes.Add(s);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

The first problem i face is when i create the int arrays i get random places in the array for example 7 indexs. But i also want to assign random heights and maybe also random positions.

So if i get in Objects_Number fro example 7 then in each one i want to have some values like random height for each one and random position for each one.

Then in the For loop some how to extract this random values and create the random Spheres. So in the end in the ArrayList myNodes i will something like:

0 = Position(5,67,0) Scale(30,4,0)

1 = Position(50,67,0) Scale(1,40,0)

And so on. Later i want to create the Spheres to display them in the Terrain when running the game.

Comment: You are complicating things, why not simply create them with a specific tag and store references to game objects instead ?

Comment: @Aybe Could you show me how to do it ? I tried using a class but got it all messed. Updated my question with what i tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create tags: *terrain*, *sphere*

Create layer: *terrain*

**Terrain**

Add terrain to scene, tip: to be able to paint you must assign textures to it first.

Assign *terrain* tag and layer to terrain.

Make sure it is centered, default size seems 500 so x/z should be -250.

[image]

**Code**

This will place spheres randomly above terrain but ensures height is according terrain below:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SphereBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _sphereCount;
    private float _sphereSize;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int SphereCount;

    public float SphereSize;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        SphereCount = Mathf.Max(0, SphereCount);
        SphereSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, SphereSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        SphereCount = 100;
        SphereSize = 20.0f;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateSpheres();
    }

    private void UpdateSpheres()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && SphereCount == _sphereCount && Mathf.Approximately(SphereSize, _sphereSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sphere");
        foreach (var t in spheres)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < SphereCount; i++)
        {
            var o = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            o.tag = "Sphere";
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(SphereSize, SphereSize, SphereSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

        _extents = Extents;
        _sphereCount = SphereCount;
        _sphereSize = SphereSize;
    }
}
```

You could also get mesh bounds of your terrain and place spheres accordingly, if terrain is not zero-centered.

**Result**

[image]

[image]

**What's next ?**

- tweak parameters as you need
- take a look at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
- accept my answer :D

Comment: Working great. I will tweak the parameters and will learn the script. Thank you very much.

Comment: Aybe why when i change the size parameter to 20 i see the size of the spheres 20 in the editor but when running the game i see them in size of 70 ? In the editor in the script in the Inspector i change it to 20 and then i click on each sphere and it's scale is realy 20,20,20 but when i'm running the game i see the scale of each one 70,70,70 even if i change the size to 100 when running the game it's size of each sphere is 70. I see the changes only in the editor when running the game it's always 70.

Comment: I also noticed now when i set it to size 20 when running the game then stop the game i see in the editor the spheres in size 70 but when i click on each sphere i see it's scale 20,20,20 strange.

Comment: It could be because some exception happens between last update and this part of the code is reached in current update ... It's hard to tell, check out your console window. Anyway code I've posted works fine, there might be something subtle going on in what you've added :)